# Exporting from Blender to Flare3D

Tags: actionscript-3, export, blender, collada, flare3d

I have created a map object in Blender, and would like to export it for use with Flare3D in Flash Builder. However, none of the texturing gets included when I try this. What is the correct way to do this so that textures get included? Or do I have to generate a UV texture map separately?

Comment: One common problem I see with the texture issues is that they are not in the proper place. Open the dae file and look for the texture files paths and cop&paste the path in browser to see if they can be opened. Another problem could be there are special charecters in the path. BTW flare3d.com/forums is the best place to get answers and they are infact very actively respond (in the weekdays)